# Zip the output files from MapReduce without merging them

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, zip, multipleoutputs

I have a MR job which uses multipleoutput format and outputs 500 files. I want to zip those files without merging them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ***`SequenceFileOutputFormat`*** : An OutputFormat that writes keys, values to SequenceFiles in binary(raw) format

You can have three variations in SequenceFile.CompressionType

**BLOCK** : Compress sequences of records together in blocks.

**NONE** : Do not compress records.

**RECORD**: Compress values only, each separately.

Key changes in your code.

```
Path outDir = new Path(WORK_DIR_PREFIX + "/out/" + jobName);

job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outDir);

SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job, CompressionType.BLOCK);
```

Have a look at working [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat) on usage of SequenceFileOutputFormat.